# using apply for two matrix

Tags: r, plot

I am new in R and dont know how to perform this. I have 2 matrix called org (20x20 matrix) and param (2x20 matrix) respectively and I want to apply the function cdfgam to each column of [org] which requires the parameters of the column a and b from [param]:

org:

```
[1    4    7]
[2    5    8]
[3    6    9]
```

param

```
 a    b
[1    4]
[2    5]
[3    6]
```

I am using:

```
JFE<-cdfgam(org[,1],para=(param[,1]))
FMA<-cdfgam(org[,2],para=(param[,2]))
MAM<-cdfgam(org[,3],para=(param[,3]))
```

Is there a way to perform this in just a line code? Also for plotting them later?

Thank You

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's not clear, at least to me, from the code. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I wanna apply the cdfgam to each column of my matrix org which requires the arguments from the matrix [param], but I want to know if there is a way to do it more efficient

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be a `for` loop, storing the results in a list.  The hardest part would be keeping your names `JFE` etc.  If that's optional, do it this way:

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:3) results[[i]] <- cdfgam(org[,i], para = param[i,])
```

(Note that you want `param[i,]`, not `param[,i]`, based on your picture of `param`, which shows a 3 by 2 matrix, not a 2 by 3 one.)

If you want to keep those names, you could add them at the end using

```
names(results) <- c("JFE", "FMA", "MAM")
```

and refer to them using code like

```
results[["FMA"]]
```

for plotting, or in a loop like

```
for (n in names(results))
  plot(results[[n]], main = paste("Results for", n))
```

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop works nice, if you really want efficiency you can still use lapply:

```
results <- lapply(1:nrow(org), function(i) cdfgam(org[,i], para = param[i,]))
names(results) <- c("JFE", "FMA", "MAM")
```

In this example the efficiency-difference is minimal, and it will also be for 20 rows.
The difference is that in the for-loop, under the hood, R stores "results" as an empty-list first.
Then "results" gets length one, so it needs another place in memory: everything is copied, and the new result is stored.
Then "results" gets length two, so it needs another place in memory: everything is copied, and the new result is stored.
Then "results" gets length three, so it needs another place in memory: everything is copied, and the new result is stored.
...

In lapply, first all results are calculated (and possibly stored spread around in memory), only then combined. Also, using lapply makes it clearer to others that you are doing independent calculations, and if you'd really want you could cut calculation into pieces (e.g. run on multiple cores).